# eclipse autogenerates !=null recursive calls

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, eclipse-jdt

given a java code such as:

```
Something v = a.getB().getC().getD().getE();
```

Is there a way in Eclipse (templates or external plugins) to generate a safe chain call as:

```
if(a!=null && 
   a.getB()!=null &&
   a.getB().getC()!=null &&
   a.getB().getC().getD()!=null &&        
   a.getB().getC().getD().getE()!=null){
          Something v = a.getB().getC().getD().getE(); 
   }
```

Comment: this is something interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you given any thought to a `try{} catch(NullPointerException e){}` block? It might feel less elegant, but it will stop your code if any of the method calls fails because the previous one returned `null`, and it will give you the chance to give the default value if it is null.

Another option would be something like this:

```
Something v = /*Default Value*/ // Will be overwritten if subsequent methods succeed.
Object temp = a.getB(); // Use whatever Object type getB() returns.
if(temp != null){
    temp = temp.getC(); 
    /* If getC() returns a different type of object, 
     * either use a different variable or make the temp variable even broader 
     * (such as the generic Object type) */
    if(temp != null){
        temp = temp.getD();
        if(temp != null){
            temp = temp.getE();
            if(temp != null)
                v = temp; 
                /* If all previous calls returned something substantial, 
                 * v will be something useful */
            }//if(getE() != null)
        }//if(getD() != null)
    }//if(getC() != null)
}//if(getB() != null)
```

If you want, you could use a slightly less CPU efficient, but easier to read, version by not nesting the if statements. If all of the if statements are executed after eachother, a single null will prevent all of the next statements from executing, although its value will still be checked every time.

As far as generating these statements, I'm not really sure. That will really depend on how far in advance you can predict what new methods will be available from the `Object` returned by previous method calls. If you're aiming for auto-generation of code, you might be better off with my first suggestion: `try-catch`

Comment: yes, do a try-catch as you suggested was the other way round: it's easier to do, though I don't like to raise exceptions that could have been controlled in another way. I finished off refactoring all the methods manually, as eclipse doesn't offer such a refactoring possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Do this only if no one will read your code. Try to avoid generated code especially the one you're asking for.

`getB()` method is called 4 extra times, etc.

By checking for null manually you'll learn coding faster and make less bugs not relying on automatic code correction ;)

Comment: thanks fot the advice but this is not an answer. I need to refactor 300 methods that do not guard against null and throw tons on NullPointerExceptions. This is why the faster I get out of it, the better, that's why I look fot an automated way to do it.

Comment: NullPointers are needed. Are you sure you'll have the logic working after you automatically refactor your code?

Comment: yes, I have a default value to assign to the expression. The annoying part is to guard against the NPE occurring during the call path.